# Limiting String length with SimpleFormatter

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm trying to limit the length of the source parameter in a SimpleFormatter format, to use in Tomcat 8.

I've read the [SimpleFormatter doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) and the [Formatter syntax doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and while I won't pretend I've understood all of the second one, following the argument by a number should limit its length.

Yet it doesn't in my tests: the lines output by

`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %4$s %n` and

`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format =%4$1s %n`

are indistinguishable.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to limit the length of the source parameter in a SimpleFormatter format, to use in Tomcat 8.

Since you only want the first character of the level then the syntax is `%4$.1s`.

Per the [java.util.Formatter JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:

```
   %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

> The **optional width** is a positive decimal integer indicating the **minimum number of characters** to be written to the output.
>
> The **optional precision** is a non-negative decimal integer usually **used to restrict the number of characters**.

Which means precision is specified using the dot character.  Since you are not concerned with a maximum If the minimum is zero then you have to omit it from the pattern.

Here is an example test case to build your pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //This really should be set as a command argument but, it works.

    //No min and max of seven chars of level.
    //System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$.7s %n");

    //Min and max of seven chars of level (right justified).
    //System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$7.7s %n");

    //Min and max of seven chars of level (left justified).
    //System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$-7.7s %n");

    //No min with max of one chars of level.
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$.1s %n");

    LogRecord r = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, "Message");
    r.setLoggerName("logger");
    r.setSourceClassName("class");
    r.setSourceMethodName("method");
    System.out.println(new SimpleFormatter().format(r));
}
```

The JavaDocs also state:

> For character, integral, and date/time **argument types** and the percent and line separator conversions, the precision is not applicable; if a precision is provided, an exception will be thrown.

Instead of 'argument types' the documentation should really say 'argument category'.  The 's' and 'S' are considered 'general' and not 'character' in the argument category table.  Which is why you can use the dot precision.

Comment: Great! Thanks! As I've said, I didn't understand everything in that doc... *shame*